# sqlite query based on selecting from column string and filtering by last rows in descending order

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlalchemy

I have a database, `tick_df`, that looks like this

```
       timestamp                             time        symbol     price
0  1649320867903 2022-04-07 08:41:07.903000+00:00  LUNA/USD:USD  108.3220
1  1649320867884 2022-04-07 08:41:07.884000+00:00   SOL/USD:USD  115.9125
2  1649320867321 2022-04-07 08:41:07.321000+00:00  LUNA/USD:USD  108.3220
3  1649320866243 2022-04-07 08:41:06.243000+00:00  LUNA/USD:USD  108.3300
4  1649320866225 2022-04-07 08:41:06.225000+00:00  AVAX/USD:USD   84.6590
5  1649320866144 2022-04-07 08:41:06.144000+00:00  AVAX/USD:USD   84.6640
```

I am trying to select all columns and the last 2 rows in descending time order from only one symbol - e.g.AVAX/USD:USD. The query I have tried is

```
SELECT symbol FROM tick_df WHERE symbol LIKE AVAX% ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT2
```

But this return an error

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) near "ORDER": syntax error
```

can anyone point to what I'm doing wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: You should enclose the `LIKE` param in single quotes, try this `SELECT symbol FROM tick_df WHERE symbol LIKE 'AVAX%' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the error message it tells you that there is a syntax error near `ORDER BY`, it hints to an error immediately before that clause.

As you can read from [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> A string constant is formed by enclosing the string in single quotes (').

You should enclose the `LIKE` arg in single quotes like this

```sql
SELECT symbol FROM tick_df WHERE symbol LIKE 'AVAX%' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 2
```

Also, if you want to return all the column you should `SELECT *` and not `SELECT symbol` because the latter will only return the symbol column.

The final correct query should be

```sql
SELECT * FROM tick_df WHERE symbol LIKE 'AVAX%' ORDER BY timestamp DESC LIMIT 2
```

Comment: that works nicely by only returns the column symbol. How can I make it return all columns of the database not just symbol?

Comment: It returns only the symbol column because you asked it with `SELECT symbol`, if you want to return all the columns you have to use `SELECT *`

Comment: cheers. yeah I figured it out. db_name = "SELECT * FROM" + " " + ("tick_df") + " " + "WHERE symbol LIKE" + " " + "'%s'" % str(names[0] + "%") + " " +  "ORDER BY timestamp DESC" + " " + "LIMIT" + " " + "2"